# Numerate values in a column regardless of order

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table like this:

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 53 |
| 2021-01-02 | 53 |
| 2021-01-03 | 53 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-12-30 | 52 |
| 2021-12-31 | 52 |

I want to rank weeks not with their values but with Date ascending order. I tried to use

> dense_rank() over (order by Week)

and got this results:

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 53 |
| 2021-01-02 | 53 |
| 2021-01-03 | 53 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-12-30 | 52 |
| 2021-12-31 | 52 |

But 53rd week is on 53rd rank, not 1st as I want. Do you know what I need to use in that case? Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [MOD](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Mathematical/MOD.htm) function in `ORDER BY`.

Because the Week Number seem like between 1 to 53, `MOD` function will calculate

- MOD(53, 53)=> 0
- MOD(1, 53) => 1

so on .... .

```
dense_rank() over (order by MOD(Week, 53))
```

Comment: wow! this is really elegant solution, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

use order by desc

```
 select *, row_number()over(order by week desc) from table_name
```

Comment: I think that would still rank week 53 as 53. They'll have to first determine what defines a week - will mostly be a weekday logic (like Sun to Sat) and use that in the calculation. I don't see a straight forward way

Comment: @ManuManjunath create table with data https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: lease do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content ([under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply play with Vertica's date/time functions - and add @D-Shih 's clever idea with the modulo function to it, and no dense-rank needed if the result is the one you display:

```
WITH
indata (dt) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2020-12-30'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-12-31'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-01-01'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-01-02'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-01-03'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-01-04'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-01-05'
[...]
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-12-30'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-12-31'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-02'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-03'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-04'
)
SELECT
  dt  
, WEEK(dt)             AS stdweek
, WEEK_ISO(dt)         AS isoweek
, MOD(WEEK(dt),53)     AS stdwkmod53
, MOD(WEEK_ISO(dt),53) AS isowkmod53
FROM indata;
-- out      dt     | stdweek | isoweek | stdwkmod53 | isowkmod53 
-- out ------------+---------+---------+------------+------------
-- out  2020-12-30 |      53 |      53 |          0 |          0
-- out  2020-12-31 |      53 |      53 |          0 |          0
-- out  2021-01-01 |       1 |      53 |          1 |          0
-- out  2021-01-02 |       1 |      53 |          1 |          0
-- out  2021-01-03 |       2 |      53 |          2 |          0
-- out  2021-01-04 |       2 |       1 |          2 |          1
-- out  2021-01-05 |       2 |       1 |          2 |          1
[...]
-- out  2021-12-30 |      53 |      52 |          0 |         52
-- out  2021-12-31 |      53 |      52 |          0 |         52
-- out  2022-01-01 |       1 |      52 |          1 |         52
-- out  2022-01-02 |       2 |      52 |          2 |         52
-- out  2022-01-03 |       2 |       1 |          2 |          1
-- out  2022-01-04 |       2 |       1 |          2 |          1
```